# default the end date based on previous week's last date

Tags: sql, mysql, where-clause, date-arithmetic

How do I go about making the in_date's end date always based on the previous week's last date?
For example, today is 24 April 2023, and the previous week's (Mon to Sun) last date was 16/04/2023

Expected SQL Query:

```
SELECT ga.in_date,
        FROM in_txn ga
        LEFT JOIN cntr_mst cm ON cm.cntr_num = ga.cntr_num
        WHERE status_active = 'A'
        and (in_date between '2020-01-01 00:00:00' and '2023-4-16 23:59:59')
```

Comment: Today is not April 24th, but April 22nd - so it would make sense to filter until last Sunday included (April 16th). If today was Monday, April 24th, wouldn’t we filter until yesterday included (Sunday, April 23rd)?

Comment: So you want the mon to sun bracket that contains the given date e.g. apr 24

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to filter from the beginning of year 2020 to the end of last week.

We can compute the date of the last Monday (or today if it’s a Monday) with `current_date` and `weekday()`:

```
current_date - interval weekday(current_date) day
```

And we can use this expression to filter with a half-open interval, voilà!

```
WHERE status_active = 'A' 
  AND in_date >= '2020-01-01'
  AND in_date <  current_date - interval weekday(current_date) day
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest this:

```
SELECT
    ga.in_date,
    DATE_SUB(DATE_ADD(DATE(ga.in_date), INTERVAL(1-DAYOFWEEK(ga.in_date)) DAY), INTERVAL 1 DAY) AS the_new_date
FROM in_txn ga
LEFT JOIN cntr_mst cm ON cm.cntr_num = ga.cntr_num
WHERE status_active = 'A' 
AND in_date >= '2020-01-01 00:00:00' AND in_date < '2023-4-17 00:00:00';
```

Also: `between` is painful! as "23:59:59" might not be the last moment of the day (the maximum precision of a MySQL TIMESTAMP column is up to microseconds , 6 digits) so it is so much easier - **and more reliable** - to avoid using it. Note that I have moved the second date up one second.

see: https://dbfiddle.uk/DL-cJL8n

Comment: can it be 'auto' to adjust the end date , meaning I don't need  to set the date as 2023-4-17 00:00:00 , it will auto calculate based on today's date that i run the SQL query